# How do I unwrap an array passed to swift using Socket.io?

Tags: swift, socket.io

I am emitting an array using socket.io like this:

```
var theArray = [true, false, true, false];

socket.on('arrayMsg', function (msg) {

    io.emit('arrayMsg', theArray);

});
```

In my swift app I see the array like this...

```
socket.on("arrayMsg"){data, ack in
        print(data[0])
    }
```

Which returns:

```
(
    1,
    0,
    1,
    0
)
```

How do I cast this into an array in Swift? I've tried all sorts of combinations of ? and ! but can't figure out how to unwrap the data.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unwrap the optional. Try with this:

```
if let dataDict = data[0] as? [Int]{
print(dataDict) }
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel this was exactly what I needed. Easy when you know how! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.IO on iOS](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/)

```
self.socket.on("win") {[weak self] data, ack in
    if let name = data?[0] as? String, typeDict = data?[1] as? NSDictionary {
        self?.handleWin(name, type: typeDict)
    } }
```

> this is new syntax for if let introduced in Swift 1.2. It simplifies
>   optional unwrapping (pyramid of doom). The important thing to gather
>   from this handler is that you do not need to force unwrap the array to
>   get the object. Also note that a JSON object will be exposed to Swift
>   as an NSDictionary.